# Jenkins - Throttle build to run on ONE job per available Node

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 Nodes (one has 4 executors), I want one of my pipeline jobs to be restricted to only running one job on each node, if the job runs concurrently on the same node then it will fail. I'm using the [throttle builds plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/throttle-concurrents/) but it doesn't work. Here's my code

```
    agent { label 'release-smoke-tests' }
options {
    throttleJobProperty(
        categories: [],
        limitOneJobWithMatchingParams: true,
        maxConcurrentPerNode: 1,
        maxConcurrentTotal: 2,
        throttleEnabled: true,
        throttleOption: 'project'
    )
}
```

With these settings the job will still run twice concurrently on a single Node, even though I have `maxConcurrentPerNode` set to 1!

Thanks for the help and please don't suggest using `disableConcurrentBuilds()` because I want them to run concurrently just not on the same build Agent. And I'd like to not limit the amount executors to 1 as they are needed for other tasks. Thanks again.

Comment: Syntax information can be found here https://github.com/jenkinsci/throttle-concurrent-builds-plugin/pull/68

Comment: You at a minimum need to pass categories I believe

Comment: No on the Get Started page it states that categories are ignored if the Throttle Option is set to 'Project'. Setting Throttle to 'categories' means 'maxConcurrentPerNode' and 'maxConcurrentTotal' will be ignored